# Ostrogradsky instability and fractional derivatives

Tags: field-theory, differentiation, stability, locality

Are [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) (or even more generally differentegrals) also under the scope of the [Ostrogradsky instability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability)?

Comment: Fractional derivative in time or space (if space then it should be OK)? May you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Well, @Quillo, the question is general to all fractional derivatives (in space,time or both in field theory with every derivative being fractional and/or only the space or time part)...Indeed, from time to time I ask myself if ALL the fractional derivatives would fall under the Ostrogradski instability or only certain subset...

Comment: I believe that only the ones in time are relevant to the instability. The problem with fractional calculus is that these operations are not local (while standard derivatives are). This already means that if your theory aims to be local and causal, it's already physically difficult to justify the use of fractional calculus in the first place, leaving out the possible instability.